# Informatica Foreign Key column population

Tags: informatica

I have two tables, `SRC` and `TGT`. I want to populate all my foreign key values in TGT from the target lookups. However, I'm getting nulls into the target. I have used all natural keys for lookup conditions. Can anyone please explain why I am seeing `nulls`?

For instance, I want to populate `foreign key` values for `MPNG_ID`, `SESN-ID`, `WRKFLW-ID` from *lookup tables* based on **repository name** and **version number**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you validate if all your Join Conditions are working fine? Probably try to replicate same query in DB and check if its giving you the same result. I assume some Join might have messed up which might result in Null values. Ensure that even the spaces are in sync if you are using Varchar value.